# что значит ошибка TabError : inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation?

Tags: python-3.x

```
def spisok_player(first_name, last_name, middle_name =' '):
    if middle_name:
    full_name = first_name + ' ' + middle_name + ' ' + last_name
    else:
        full_name = first_name + last_name
        return full_name.title()
user = spisok_player('adam', 'colins')
user = spisok_player('john', 'hooker', 'less')
print(user)
```

Начинающий программист не понимаю где ошибка...
высвечивается

```
full_name = first_name + ' ' + middle_name + ' ' + last_name
                                                               ^
TabError: inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation
```

Comment: @extrn С одной стороны, таких вопросов уже 100500, а с другой стороны, код то каждый раз разный )

Comment: @CrazyElf в данном случае, как мне кажется, существующих ответов достаточно для решения этой и очень многих похожих проблем

Answer (score 3):

Надо верно расставить табуляции/пробелы, вот так:

```
def spisok_player(first_name, last_name, middle_name = None):
    if middle_name:
        full_name = first_name + ' ' + middle_name + ' ' + last_name
    else:
        full_name = first_name + ' ' + last_name
    return full_name.title()

user = spisok_player('adam', 'colins')
print(user)
user = spisok_player('john', 'hooker', 'less')
print(user)
```

Вывод:

```
Adam Colins
John Less Hooker
```

И обратите внимание, что в строке с `return` у вас была лишняя табуляция. Интерпретатор при этом не ругается, но при срабатывании `if ... :` функция возвращает `None` из-за того, что не срабатывает `return`.

Я ещё некоторые правки внёс в ваш код - параметр по умолчанию лучше передавать `None`, например.

А вообще эту функцию можно записать в одну строку, используя тернарный оператор `if`:

```
def spisok_player(first_name, last_name, middle_name = None):
    return (first_name + ' ' + ((middle_name + ' ') if middle_name else '') + last_name).title()
```